# How to convert varchar to datetime, not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have imported some columns from a textfile into my table `stuff`.

I had to import date as `varchar(255)`. I want to convert datatype from `varchar` to `datetime`.

The format of date data is:

```
6/2/2018 3:00:00 PM
6/2/2018 4:00:00 PM
6/2/2018 5:00:00 PM
```

I have tried the following without success :

```
select datum from stuff str_to_date(datum, %d/%m/%Y)
```

and :

```
select datum from stuff where convert(datetime,datum,103);
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to be? What does "without success" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your queries is not correct.

[`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is indeed meant to convert a string to a date. As a second argument, it expects a string (not a litteral string !) that represents the format of the input string.

Given the format of your date, you may use :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('6/2/2018 3:00:00 PM', '%e/%c/%Y %l:%i:%s %p')
```

Format specifier details :

- `%e` : Day of the month, numeric (`0..31`)
- `%c` : Month, numeric (`0..12`)
- `%Y` : Year, numeric, four digits
- `%l` : Hour (`1..12`)
- `%i` : Minutes, numeric (`00..59`)
- `%s` : Seconds (`00..59`)
- `%p` : `AM` or `PM`

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=239b16756b21bf2a2a8b78cda81f95f7)**

---

If you are actually looking to convert the datatype of the column, then you would need to create a temporary column, update it with converted data, then drop the original column and rename the temporary, like :

```
ALTER TABLE stuff ADD (datum_new datetime);
UPDATE stuff SET datum_new = STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%e/%c/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');
ALTER TABLE stuff DROP datum;
ALTER TABLE stuff CHANGE COLUMN datum_new datum datetime;
```

If you are using MySQL 8.0, the last statement can be written as :

```
ALTER TABLE stuff RENAME COLUMN datum_new TO datum;
```

Comment: Hello, thx for help. 
I get ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: ''6/2/2009 3:00:00 PM'' for function str_to_date on second line. 
UPDATE stuff SET datum_new = STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%e/%c/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');

Comment: It seems like there are additional single quotes around the string... Try : `UPDATE stuff SET datum_new = STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(datum,"'",''), '%e/%c/%Y %l:%i:%s %p');`

Comment: I had to use %m/%d/%Y  or it would only convert 300 post out of 700 .